# Minimum Number of Steps to reach Same Position

Tags: java, python, arrays, loops, counting

I tried to solve a coding challenge, but I haven't found a good solution yet. The problem is as follows:

- Given an **array of size N of integers** (positive and/or negative), you must **find the minimum number of iterations so that all the elements of the array reach the same value**. In case it can't be done, the result is -1.
- In each iteration, **all of the elements** of the array must take one step (either +1 or -1).

For example, if you start with an array `[4 2 0]`, the minimum number of iterations would be 3 because `[4 2 0] -> [3 1 1] ->[2 2 2]`. On the other hand, if you have `[1 0]`, then the answer would be -1 (it's impossible that the elements reach the same value).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly I think the key comes from noticing:

```
[4, 0], [4, 2, 0], [4, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0]
```

All have the same answer. The only two things that matter are:

1. knowing the minimum and the maximum
2. that all numbers have the same parity

So step through the list and at each point check the minimum, the maximum and make sure the entry at that point has the same parity as all the other numbers.

In python this might look like:

```
current_min, current_max  = float("inf"), float("-inf")
parity = numbers[0] % 2
for entry in numbers:
    if entry % 2 != parity:
        return -1
    current_min, current_max = min(entry, current_min), max(entry, current_max)
return (current_max - current_min) / 2
```